# how to build rpc from protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am writing "raft consensus algorithm" with boost::asio and protobuf. Servers communicate with each other by using two types of "RPC": AppendEntryRPC and RequestVoteRPC. When Server A received a length-known string from Server B, how does it known which kind of RPC struct should the string be decoded into?

I know there is a naive solution to this problem by splitting the receiving stage into two stage: the first stage get the RPC type name, the second stage get the RPC string content then decode it. But I just want to avoid doing so. Is there any solutions?

Also I know there is a framework called "grpc", but I can't successfully run its example on my Mac. Or can someone explain how "grpc" solve this problem in the naive language please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no solutions for that. The servers cannot identify a message type, it has to be known in advance. Reason every message / RPC can have a different protobuff proto file to deserialize.

The best way is to build a header system with a known structure so you know with what to deserialize.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an additional message that can contain both type of messages and is always safe to parse:

```proto
message Vote {
  ...
}

message Entry {
  ...
}

message VoteOrEntry {
  oneof combined {
    Vote vote = 1;
    Entry entry = 2;
  }
}
```

Then use `has_vote()` and `has_entry()` to distinguish between your cases.

You will still only have one message of type `VoteOrEntry`. For your new sample project added above, this `write.cc` should to the job:

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <google/protobuf/util/time_util.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "test.pb.h"

using namespace std;

using google::protobuf::util::TimeUtil;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;

    if (argc != 2) {
        cerr << "Usage:  " << argv[0] << " ADDRESS_BOOK_FILE" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cap cap;
    int type;
    cout << "Please choose a type [1, 2]: ";
    cin >> type;

    if (type == 1) {
        type1 *t1 = cap.mutable_entity1();
        string name;
        cout << "Please choose a name: ";
        cin >> name;
        int id;
        cout << "Please choose an id: ";
        cin >> id;
        t1->set_name(name);
        t1->set_id(id);

        fstream output(argv[1], ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
        if(!cap.SerializeToOstream(&output)){
            cerr<<"failed to write to file"<<endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }else{
      type2 *t2 = cap.mutable_entity2();
      int id;
      cout << "Please choose an id: ";      
      cin>>id;
      string name;
      cout << "Please choose a name: ";
      cin>>name;
      int v;
      cout << "Please choose v: ";
      cin>>v;
      t2->set_name(name);
      t2->set_id(id);
      t2->set_v(v);
      fstream output(argv[1], ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
      if(!cap.SerializeToOstream(&output)){
          cerr<<"failed to write to file"<<endl;
          return -1;
      }
    }

    google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is possible but restricting, RPC mostly have varying structures field etc. It would make sense to have it in error or status handling since it should be standardized for all parties.

Comment: Thanks, "oneof combied" is actually what I am looking for, though can't understand the conversation between you.

Comment: @Jan-Gerd. Bro, can you give me an example.  Because I can't write an example program "writer and reader" like the official "address book" example(especially the write).  Nor can I google it.

Comment: "write(37139,0x10a25f5c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f8cfe500000: pointer being freed was not allocated
write(37139,0x10a25f5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug" it keep complaining with a set_allocated_vote or set_allocated_entry

Comment: @YNX, please post your code somewhere, then I can take a look. If this is no longer related to RPC, please create a new question for it.